# Running small snippets of code persistently in Chrome (eg. tiny extensions)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Can I run small script snippets in Chrome all the time, as they were mini extensions? Without the manifest and packaging involved with a regular extension?

I basically want to "hack" Chrome to send events when I press media keys. A script like so:

```
sendRequest = function(action) {
  return chrome.extension.sendRequest({
    action: action
  }, (function() {}));
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 32) {
    return sendRequest("pause");
  } else if (e.keyCode === 37) {
    return sendRequest("previous");
  } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
    return sendRequest("next");
  }
});
```

I'm imagining this can be added via the Sources tab and some of the new magic there, but not sure.

Comment: Note that [`chrome.extension.sendRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-sendRequest) was already deprecated in Chrome 20. Extensions should use [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage).

Answer (score 2):

The extensions API (`chrome.extension.sendRequest`) is not available to non-extensions, obviously. A real mini-extension should do the job.

Comment: Thanks, that's about all I needed to know :)